# How to save browser cookies in ram?

Tags: memory, security, browser, internet-security

I have a laptop I use in public where I access some sensible information over the browser. I already encrypted it and cookies are automatically deleten when I close the browser. The problem is, if somebody could find out the password, that person could maybe recover the cookies and access my private data. I know the RAM has nothing saved when the laptop is powered off, so it would be a good idea to save my cookies there.

**Is there a way to save cookies in the RAM?**

Comment: In Firefox, there's an option in Options/Preferences / Security to store cookies for the current session only, which means they'll be (or should be) deleted when you close the browser. Problem is, some cookies are crafted so they have a pre-determined shelf life, and are copied to disk no matter what. Disabling disk cache could help too.

Comment: RAM is volatile memory, if you turn the computer off, then the data is lost.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I want.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: @harrymc Chromium-based if possible. I'm using Windows, so I can't use Safari.

Comment: Have you tried the **Incognito Mode** of your web browser? Not saving Cookies is one of the features of this mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already set Chrome to
[Delete cookies after you close Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en),
which is all that can be done with standard Chrome/Chromium.
You need an extension for doing more.

You may try to use the extension
[Cookie AutoDelete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-autodelete/fhcgjolkccmbidfldomjliifgaodjagh?hl=en).
This extension is activated by closing the tab and it does a clean sweep of all
the site data : Cookies, IndexedDB, Localstorage, etc.

A more aggressive extension is
[Super History & Cache Cleaner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-history-cache-clean/afelaengidkffdcabnhdoeojoeoonfcn?hl=en)
which can clear browser history, cache and cookies on a selected interval.
This one might be too aggressive.